# Create three (or higher) dimensional array with Julia

Tags: arrays, julia

In Julia, the `;` may be used to create a two-dimensional array.

```
julia> [1 2; 3 4]
2x2 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2
 3  4
```

Is it possible to use a similar syntax to create a three-dimensional (or higher-dimensional) array? The following works, but I am unsure as to whether or not there is a cleaner, better way.

```
julia> reshape(collect(1:8), 2, 2, 2)
2x2x2 Array{Int64,3}:
[:, :, 1] =
 1  3
 2  4

[:, :, 2] =
 5  7
 6  8
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I suppose the cleanest manual syntax is via the `cat` command, e.g.:

```
cat(3, [1 2 ;3 4], [5 6 ; 7 8]);   % concatenate along the 3rd dimension
```

Comment: If you define `zcat(args...) = cat(3,args...)`, then perhaps `zcat([1 2 ; 3 4],[5 6 ; 7 8])` is clean/clear.

Comment: @DanGetz one could go a little further and use one of the available binary infix operators, like: `const ++ = zcat; [1 2; 3 4] ++ [5 6; 7 8] ++ [9 10; 11 12]` for example.

Answer (score 5):

I think you want a list comprehension? This will make it easier when you have more complicated arrays to create.

Something like:

```
[x+1 for x=1:first, y=1:second, z=1:third]
```

will give a `first X second X third` dimensional array populated by `x+1`.

see http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.4/manual/arrays/#comprehensions for more info :)

Comment: This works, but I was wondering if there was a specific syntax for 3D array creation, given all of the values. For 2D arrays, there is `[1 2; 3 4]` (as a replacement for `reshape([1 3 2 4], 2, 2)`) - is there a way to extend the syntax to work with 3D+ arrays?

Comment: It's not really necessary, since it would be so cumbersome for anything bigger than 2 x 2 x 2,  and the ease of using reshape.